# Custom soap Webservice In Salesforce

Tags: apex, webservices, soap

I am developing a custom webservice in that from third party application i am getting the different inputs they are

```
product1--> comments on products--> quantity1--> proposel price1
                                 >> quantity2--> proposel price2
```

That means i am getting different quantities and different proposel prices for same product1  how can i map that different quanties and different proposel prices in my webservice can any one give me some sample code for that,

Comment: What have you tried or build yourself so far ? It is a bit unclear whether you're asking how to build a soap webservice in apex, or how to create your business logic. If this is as uncear to others, they may vote your question to be closed. Feel free to update with additional explination or your current code.

Comment: Is the 3rd party providing a WSDL file that describes the webservice? If they do you could automatically generate the Apex code from WSDL. Or you might look into XML parsing functions in Apex... Is it "push" or "pull"? I mean does Salesforce make a callout and get the data from them or will they push data to SF themselves?

Comment: I don't think you can do it :/ As far as I know Pricebooks don't have the concept of rebates, volume-based discounts etc. They're simply list prices available in a timeframe from-to. In a way it's up to you how you'd like to implement it, maybe by having your own related list of "Pricing rules" under Product2...